# Understanding nested Namespace and its scope

Tags: php

1. Suppose there are namespaces A and A\B respectively.

In the scope of A, can I refer a class named C within A\B just C without prepending B\?

2. Why there are no prepending global indicator \ in namespaces? eg ) namespace \A;

Comment: Can you please add  more resonable examples of code ?

Comment: @AlexKapustin I'm asking in general cases. Whether I can call a class within sub namespaces by just its name is first one and is prepending global indicator ￦ in namespace declaration a doable is the second.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Well... I meant global indicator. Just like in ￦stdClass or ￦Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose there are namespaces A and A\B respectively.

No there is A and B is inside it.

> In the scope of A, can I refer a class named C within A\B just C
>   without prepending B\?

Yes if you are in A\B you can use `C`

```
<?php
namespace A\B;

class C {}
```

Is accessible in code which is like:

```
<?php
namespace A;

$C = new B\C;
```

Or

```
<?php
namespace A\B;

$C = new C;
```

But you cant jump to C without letting the autoloader know about B as it will look for a class in A called C, but C is in B.

```
<?php
namespace A;

$C = new C;
```

> Why there are no prepending global indicator \ in namespaces? eg )
>   namespace \A;

There is, you cant do:

```
<?php
namespace A\B;

$C = new \A\B\C;

// but not
$C = new A\B\C;
```

If you want a global namespace you cant do:

```
<?php
namespace;
```

Or

```
<?php
namespace \;
```

But you can do:

```
<?php
namespace {
    class A {}
}
```

Which is like no namespace at all.

> What is the relationship between the scope created by function and by
>   namespace?

Function scope does not have anything to do with namespaces.

But a function declared in a namespace, is in a namespace and only accessible through its namespace.

```
<?php
namespace A;

function B() {
    echo 'Value B';
}

echo B();
// or
echo \A\B();

// this wont work
echo \B();
```

Comment: My first question was, in namespace A, can I refer a class A￦B￦C just by C since B is subset of A. And second one was whether i can declare a namespace prepended by global ￦

Comment: No, you need to define the full namespace/path to the file so the autoloader can autoload.

Comment: *can declare a namespace prepended by global*, if you dont define a namespace its in global.

Comment: Np, glad to help.

Comment: Just wanted to add that:
it's not neccesarry to use `$C = new \A\B\C;`

You can write: `use A\B\C as myABC;`

and in code use: `$C = new myABC();`